# Check if result is near a borderline in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have a set of marks as follows

| NAME | SCORE |
| --- | --- |
| AVA | 13 |
| BERTIE | 46 |
| GRAHAM | 87 |

And a table of grade boundaries as follows:

| GRADE | BOUNDARY |
| --- | --- |
| A | 88 |
| B | 45 |
| C | 9 |

How can I easily make a formula in Excel such that it...

1. Looks at the mark someone gets
2. Checks if it is with (say) 2 marks of any of the grade boundaries
3. Returns a YES if the score is within that range else a NO
4. Returns how far above or below the relevant boundary they are.

So for the above, desired result is:

| NAME | SCORE | BORDERLINE? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AVA | 13 | NO |
| BERTIE | 46 | YES +1 |
| GRAHAM | 87 | YES -1 |

I've lost myself in nested if statements and in VLOOKUP and can't see the wood for the trees...

Comment: The easiest way is to expand your table of grade boundaries, adding rows with all valid values and a column with ready-made “Yes+1”. In this case, you won't have to build a very complex formula; MATCH() will be enough to find the desired row and INDEX() to get the value. And if MATCH() does not find a score in the table, then IFERROR() will return “NO”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have CONCAT function in your Excel (2019+) you can try a formula like this:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(IF(ABS(C17-$H$17:$H$19)<=2,"YES " & TEXT(C17-$H$17:$H$19,"+0;-0"), " ")),"   ","NO"))
```

[image: borderline]

Comment: Excellent thanks so much!